# Google MailApp (Javascript) and PRE tag

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to produce an HTML button in a mail message - sending from the Javascript "flavour"of GAS MailApp.

I have tried three different mail readers to eliminate that cause (Thunderbird, Mac Mail and Chrome)

I am sending this HTML via the htmlBody, advanced, parameter of the MailApp:

```
  <script>function blah()
     {alert('hi');
}</script>"+
    "<input type<pre>=</pre>'submit' id<pre>=</pre>'deleteBookingButton' 
 value<pre>=</pre>'Delete booking' onclick<pre>=</pre>'this.disabled<pre>=</pre>true;blah()'></br>";
```

and the message is rendered as:

```
<script>function blah(){alert('hi=
');}</script><input type<pre>=3D</pre>'submit' id<pre>=3D</pre>'deleteBooki=
ngButton' value<pre>=3D</pre>'Delete booking' onclick<pre>=3D</pre>'this.di=
sabled<pre>=3D</pre>true;blah()'></br>9fgnbterk48818il9j3c933fa0@google.com=
</br>
```

As you can see the equals signs are not being rendered correctly.

I have tried escaping the equals sign

```
 (&eq; &#61;)
```

and CDATA.

If at all possible I'd like a raw (ie not Node or similar) solution

Comment: Wow! This has led me to some interesting investigations - but not yet a solution. In short:

Comment: Wow! This has led me to some interesting investigations - but not yet a solution. In short:

1) Using **HtmlService**.createHtml... I was able to locate a problem in my first try. Failure to escape < and > for PRE.
2) With that fixed create... was **still unable** to understand my HTML however code.gs could!
3) The prevailing issue is that the escaped <> signs are still not un-escaped, and given effect, by any of the email readers - '&lt;pre&gt;=&lt;/pre&gt;'